# cannot change focus outline on .custom-control-input in boostrap4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying for hours to change the focus outline color of the custom boostrap controls.

I am able to change the background easily with:

```
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator {
background-color: red; 
}
```

But I cannot target the outline color for some reason...
I have tried:

```
input.custom-control-input:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    outline-color: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;

}
```

```
Has anyone run into this issue yet?

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robsilva/ht1cjLrb/1/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator {
  background-color: red!important;
}

.custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-indicator {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-description">Check this custom checkbox</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the :focus state because that's what's showing the border in the inspector... I didn't realize it was coming from the actual elements. Thank you, Atul.